# Error while uploading file from android to cpanel

Tags: android, http, file-upload, cpanel

The server blocks a text file upload from and android application ...
//message
security alert.This file has been blocked as it may contain Trojan/virus.Any further attempts may block the IP address.
sever(CPANEL) .
Can anyone help me as to how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared the problem with hosting space provider !!!